# how to simply return a column if some condition is true?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named A:

```
DATETIME_START || DATETIME_END || VALUE 
 --------------------------------------- 
2012-07-23     || 2013-07-23   ||  coffee  
2011-13-11     || 2013-01-09   ||  airport
```

all I am trying to do is - if the time of request is between `DATETIME_START` and `DATETIME_END`, simply return `VALUE`.

I tried:

```
SELECT 
IF (NOW() BETWEEN A.DATETIME_START AND A.DATETIME_END, VALUE,NULL)
FROM A
```

but what happens is that I get the string `"IF (NOW() BETWEEN A.DATETIME_START AND A.DATETIME_END, VALUE,NULL)"` in the result!

**(I don't want to put the condition in the WHERE)**

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column name will be whatever you actually select. Say your select had looked like this instead:

```
SELECT
    IF (NOW() BETWEEN A.DATETIME_START AND A.DATETIME_END, ColumnA, ColumnB)
```

What should the resultset column name be when you are potentially getting results from 2 columns?

You may not even be selecting from any columns:

```
SELECT
    IF(0 < 1, 'True', 'False')
```

In your particular case you didn't really need an IF statement, but when you do have e.g. conditions or functions in your SELECT, you can use 
[Alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28SQL%29)
 to determine the column name yourself.

```
SELECT
    IF(0 < 1, 'True', 'False') AS YourName
  # or
    IF(0 < 1, 'True', 'False') AS `Your name with spaces`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT VALUE FROM A
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN A.DATETIME_START AND A.DATETIME_END
```

Comment: I would like not to use the condition in the WHERE, sorry, edited.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN NOW() BETWEEN A.DATETIME_START AND A.DATETIME_END THEN VALUE
        ELSE NULL
    END
FROM A
```